# Forms LDAP authentication works some of the time

Tags: c#, forms, authentication, ldap

I recently created a website that uses Forms authentication using `LDAP` as its membership provider, as per the `microsoft doco` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx

When I deployed this to our production server, it will authenticate some users, and not others? Could this be because I am binding to a specific `LDAP server`:

```
*add name="ADConn" connectionString="LDAP://xbwis04/DC=fake,DC=com,DC=au"*
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That really depends upon the structure of your domain/forest

Answer (score 0):

Have you got multiple Windows Domains in one Forest ?

If so, can you try to build your connection string on a Domain Controler (DC) which own a Global Catalog (GC). This one is supposed to know all the objects of a Windows Forest.

```
add name="ADConn" connectionString="LDAP://GCComputer/DN-Root"
```